# Como eliminar la hora de DateAdd en Expression Reporting Service

Tags: vb, ssrs

Estoy tratando de completar una expresión (calcular valor de un parámetro)
¿Cómo elimino el tiempo de la función "Now"? esta es mi expresion:

```
=IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today))="Monday",DateAdd("d", -7, Today),DateAdd("d", 0, Today))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, estuve investigando y llegue a esta respuesta:

```
=IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", DateValue(Now)))="Monday", 
FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d", -7,DateValue(Now)),DateFormat.ShortDate), 
FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d", 0, DateValue(Now)),DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

Ademas de agregar el Datavalue tambien agregue un FormatDateTime con un ShorDate para especificar que solo necesito la fecha.
Espero que a alguien más le pueda servir, gracias por sus respuestas igualmente.

Comment: Genial. Perfecto :)